# phone number validation in textbox

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I used Magento phone number validation `validate-length maximum-length-11 minimum-length-11 validate-digits` for phone number but i want to first digit starting with(7,8,9) and after that 9 digit will come how i restrict ?

Comment: how many digit altogether?

Comment: I got a solution check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got answer to my question

```
<input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?> validate-mobileno" id="billing:telephone" placeholder="Mobile"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if(Validation) {
Validation.addAllThese([
['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:919986858483)',
function(v){
var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
// var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
if(v.length > 0){
if(v.length !=12){
    return false;
   }else if(v[0] != 9 || v[1] != 1 ){

    return false;
   }else if(v[2]!=9 && v[2]!=8 && v[2]!=7){

    return false;
   }


return true;

}else {
return false;
}

}
]])};
 var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this file `custom-validate.js` and place in `js` folder.

```
Validation.add('validate-phoneLax', 'Please enter a number starting from 7 or 8 or 9 and should be exactly 11 digits. For example 71234567890', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^7[0-9]{10}$/g.test(v) || /^8[0-9]{10}$/g.test(v) || /^9[0-9]{10}$/g.test(v)
})
```

Now just need to call this file from xml so that it is added in that particular page. If you want it to be in every page then just add in `local.xml`

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>custom-validate.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Now when you have `validate-phoneLax` class name in input filed it should validate as you expect.

**Remember**

We are overriding `phoneLax` validation class.

I haven't tested but should work.

[More Reading](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

Add your own validation class

```
Validation.add('Your Class Name','Your Validation Message',function(v){
    return "check Your patterns here";
});
```